# When will constraints in an LP be satisfied as equalities?

Tags: linear-programming

Say $\mathbf{X}$ is a $n\times m$ matrix with no negative entries. Assume further that every row and every column have at least a non zero element. Denote $\langle\mathbf{X}\rangle$ the cone spanned by $\mathbf{X}$. Let $\mathbf{q},\mathbf{k}, 1$, and $0$ be vectors of the suitable dimension. In the following LP
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
  \text{maximize} &\quad \mathbf{q}\cdot 1\\
  \text{subject to} & \quad \mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{q}\leq\mathbf{k}\\ &\quad\mathbf{q}\geq 0,
\end{array}$$

let $\mathbf{q}^*$ be its solution. I see that $\mathbf{k}\not\in\langle\mathbf{X}\rangle\implies \mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^*\leq\mathbf{k}$ (with $\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^*\ne\mathbf{k}$), because $\mathbf{k}\not\in\langle\mathbf{X}\rangle$ implies that there does not exist a set of positive weights satisfying $\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{k}$.

However, I believe that $\mathbf{k}\in\langle\mathbf{X}\rangle\implies \mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^*=\mathbf{k}$. Is this true? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true. Consider $$X^{T}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 6\\
1 & 3
\end{array}\right],\ k=\left[\begin{array}{c}
7\\
4
\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: Thanks. I've posted a follow up question on this in case you care to take a look: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/will-constraints-in-this-lp-be-satisfied-as-equalities